# C debugging variations generator

Tags: c, debugging, combinatorics

I would like to ask for help with debugging this simple piece of C code:

```
void generator (int place, char *array, int n, int lol){
int i;
char c[6]={'1','0','+','-','*','/'};

if(n==0){
printf("%s\n",array);
return;
}
for(i=0; i<6; i++){
    if (lol==0){
        if (i>1) break;
        array[place]=c[i];
        lol=1;
        generator(place+1, array, n-1, lol);
    }
    if(lol==1){
        array[place]=c[i];
        if(i>1){
            lol=0;
            generator(n+1, array, n, lol);
        }
        else{ lol=1;
    generator(place+1, array, n-1, lol);}
    }
}}
```

The function is supposed to generate strings which contain n 1s and 0s separated by 0 to n-1 operators
For example if n==3 then the output should be:

```
111
1+11
11+1
1+1+1
1*11
11*1
1*1*1
....
0/00
00/0
0/0/0
000
```

I'm a beginner programmer so would appreciate any tips.

Comment: In your code, you have the variable '`lol`' but its name and purpose are inscrutable (at least, I can't scrute it; you presumably have a purpose in mind).

Answer (score 1):

Every call to the function is using the same array, and you "insert" symbols by over-writing an existing element of the array. Neither of these is what you want to happen.

Also, how are you calling the function? What is initially contained in the 'array'?

Comment: fist time i call the function like this: generator(0, array, n, 0); and the array is initialy empty just alocated

Comment: Don't pass an array to the function; make it use a local array, dynamically allocated to an appropriate size. That way you get a separate data chunk for each call, which you require for correctness. Make sure you account for the symbols you're going to insert when setting the array size, and free() what you malloc().

Comment: Also, try writing out the pseudocode first so you can see exactly what needs to be done.

Comment: @boone: If you can use C99, then use VLAs to allocate arrays of the appropriate size.

Comment: FWIW, this will be easier if you always insert something - put a space if there should be no operator. That way everything is always lined up the same way, which makes the string operations much simpler. Then you can adjust the part where you output the strings to just skip over spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider studying backtracking algorithms, since in my opinion this is a backtracking problem.